# I have a macro program which splits file and protects the sheet but I am unable to put autofilter and sort in the individual workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro program that parses through a worksheet and creates new work book based on one particular column. In my case new workbooks will be created based on column 3. Also I have written a call function to protect the individual workbooks with a password. Only few columns are editable and the rest of the columns are read only. Now I want to apply auto filter and sort function so that the user can search information based on their need and enter values in the editable cells. However when we protect the sheet autofilter doesn't work. Can you help in adding autofilter function on a protected sheet for each individual workbooks.
**Sample code shown for reference.**

```
    Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer


    vcol = 3

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:Z1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
        ws.Columns(icol).Clear

        For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
            ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""

            If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then

                '===================================================================
                '~~Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
                Workbooks.Add
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(0).Name = myarr(i) & ""
                '===================================================================

            Else
                Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            End If

            '==========================================================================
            '~~ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
             '~~Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
            ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
            'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("T2:T1000").Formula = "=SUM(Q2:S2)"
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Macros\Split_Files\" & myarr(i) & ".xlsx"
            '=========================================================================
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Next

        ws.AutoFilterMode = False
        ws.Activate
        Call ProtectAll
    End Sub


    Sub ProtectAll()
        Dim wBk As Workbook
        Dim sFileSpec As String
        Dim sPathSpec As String
        Dim sFoundFile As String
        Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim LastRow As Long

        sPathSpec = "C:\Macros\Split_Files\"
        sFileSpec = "*.xlsx"

        sFoundFile = Dir(sPathSpec & sFileSpec)
        Do While sFoundFile <> ""
            Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)
            With wBk

                Set mainworkBook = wBk
                 'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Unprotect passowrd = "abc"
                 Set ws1 = mainworkBook.Sheets(1)
                LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row

                mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("U2:U" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUM(R2:T2)"




                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A:Z").Locked = True
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Locked = False
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("Q:S").Locked = False
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("U:U").Locked = False
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Range("W:X").Locked = False

                mainworkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Protect passowrd = "abc"

                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).Protect passowrd:="abc", userinterfaceonly:=True
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).EnableOutlining = True
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).EnableAutoFilter = True
                'mainworkBook.Sheets(1).EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells


                Worksheets(2).Visible = xlSheetHidden
                Worksheets(3).Visible = xlSheetHidden



                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wBk.SaveAs Filename:=.FullName
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End With
            Set wBk = Nothing
            Workbooks(sFoundFile).Close False
            sFoundFile = Dir
        Loop

End Sub
```

Regards,
Linu

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort in a protected sheet you would have to unprotect it and protect it again afterwards.
But you could use the filter function even when the sheet is protected, just not sort.

Here are two little functions I used for on of my projects:

```
Function protect_sheet(sheetname As String)
If Sheets(sheetname).ProtectContents = False Then
    Sheets(sheetname).Protect Password:=Password, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End If
End Function

Function unprotect_sheet(sheetname As String)
    If Sheets(sheetname).ProtectContents = True Then
        Sheets(sheetname).Unprotect Password:=Password
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: But I have a doubt with it whether it will work on a non macro file. The source file is a macro file but the out put file generated is a non macro file. I had tried with autofilter option as true but in the protected sheet it doesn't allow to filter. For the time being I can avoid sorting. I can share the file if you give me your id?